# Expected value of the maximum of poisson distributed variable and 0

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, poisson-distribution

I want to find the expected value of max{S-X,0}, where X is Poisson(lambda) distributed and S is a fixed number. 
I am looking for the notation with integrals.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit how you tried to solve it, at least your thoughts, so other people could help you better. Good luck!

Comment: The notation for expectation won't involve integrals because a Poisson distribution involves *discrete* values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\max\left(S-x,0\right)f(x)
$$
where 
$$
f(x) = \frac{\lambda^x\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda}}{x!}
$$
since the max leads to all values of $k$ greater than $S$ then the payoff is zero thus we can limit the summation
$$
\sum_{x=0}^{S}\left(S-x\right)f(x)
$$

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. This will work!